# How to make [HandlerAttribute]-based interception work on everything by default in Unity?

Tags: unity-container, unity-interception

I want to use `[HandlerAttribute]`-based interception in my project (because it is slightly more obvious to the new developers). However I can't get it to work unless I explicitly specify `new InterceptionBehavior<PolicyInjectionBehavior>()` in `RegisterType`.

Is there an easy way to enable `[HandlerAttribute]` detection on everything without polluting `RegisterType` calls?

Answer (score 1):

I think the following should achieve what you're after

Define a `UnityContainerExtension` like so:

```
public class InterceptionExtension : UnityContainerExtension
{
    protected override void Initialize()
    {
        Context.Registering += OnRegister;
        Context.RegisteringInstance += OnRegisterInstance;
    }

    public override void Remove()
    {
        Context.Registering -= OnRegister;
        Context.RegisteringInstance -= OnRegisterInstance;
    }

    private void OnRegister(object sender, RegisterEventArgs e)
    {
        Container.Configure<Interception>()
            .SetInterceptorFor(e.TypeTo, new VirtualMethodInterceptor());
    }

    private void OnRegisterInstance(object sender, RegisterInstanceEventArgs e)
    {
        Container.Configure<Interception>()
            .SetInterceptorFor(e.RegisteredType, new VirtualMethodInterceptor());
    }
}
```

Add this to the container:

```
_container.AddNewExtension<InterceptionExtension>();
```

Then for every registered type, this should configure `Interception` to apply on virtual members. This should then pick up on any applied `[HandlerAttribute]`s.

Comment: The proposed solution as I understand it will not pick up `[HandlerAttribute]` since my main problem is `PolicyInjectionBehavior`, not `Interceptor`. However the idea itself is correct I think, I'll just replace `SetInterceptorFor` with adding the policy behavior.